# Css for emoji img tags in display flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have editable  content div with emojiareaone integrated
To center the content i used

```
{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: center;
   align-content: center;
   text-align: center;
}
```

it displays  test in right positions  but

all emojis   tags in separate rows

[image: emoji image]

is there any way to  display as  it was entered

Comment: All emojis are in separate rows because you are using `flex-direction: column;` You can upload your code here to let other people help you more easily.

Answer (score 0):

You Can try This .

```
  emoji-tag {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```